# delayactivity not setting

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to set the delay activity programatically in a state machine workflow using Visual studio with SharePoint2010.

This is being set in the method.

```
private void delayActivity1_InitializeTimeoutDuration(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.delayActivity1.TimeoutDuration = System.TimeSpan.Parse("00:30:00");

        }
```

Unfortunately the timeoutduration is being ignored and the setting in the GUI properties is being used.
I put in a breakpoint in the method and it does indeed show TimeoutDuration being set correctly.
It look like a bug. Is there anyway to get this to work pls

Answer (score 1):

The remarks section for [DelayActivity.InitializeTimeoutDuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.workflow.activities.delayactivity.initializetimeoutduration%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) states:

> This event should not be used to set the TimeoutDuration for a DelayActivity. The time-out duration should be set in the workflow's InitializeComponent method instead.